# Convert number from 0 to 16581375 to RGBin python

Tags: python, pygame, rgb

Is there any way in which, given a number between 0 and 16581375 `(255*255*255)` to an RGB value- such as 0 at `(0,0,0)` and 16581375 as `(255,255,255)`?

Obviously, in addition to this, there are factors such as he ordering of RGB values, and different factors in themselves.

The reason I am asking this question is because in order to get greater resolution of a mathematical structure I need more colours (rather than just 255 shades of grey).

So, is there any way in which I can do this?

Comment: Do you mean 16777216 (256 * 256 * 256) ?

Comment: whats your question now? do you want to make a random `rgb` value ?

Comment: In answer to the above question, no. Considering pygame only goes up to (255,255,255)?

Comment: And to jonrsharpe: I am not sure.Is there any way in which the system could be fixed- so the combination goes from low to high?

Comment: @user2592835 You need to explain how to get RGB from a single value. It is clear that `value = R * G * B` but how do you divide them up?

Comment: ...then you wouldn't be able to represent all colours, only those for which `r < g < b`. (And the examples should have been e.g. `(125, 192, 250)`, `(200, 120, 250)`, `(240, 125, 200)`, as `300` isn't in range!)

Answer (score 0):

Not very sexy, but...

... given your sample value:

```
>>> n = 16581375
>>> h = "{:06X}".format(n)
>>> (int(h[0:2],16),int(h[2:4],16),int(h[4:6],16))
(253, 2, 255)
```

The min:

```
>>> n = 0
>>> h = "{:06X}".format(n)
>>> (int(h[0:2],16),int(h[2:4],16),int(h[4:6],16))
(0, 0, 0)
```

The max:

```
>>> n = 256*256*256-1
>>> h = "{:06X}".format(n)
>>> (int(h[0:2],16),int(h[2:4],16),int(h[4:6],16))
(255, 255, 255)
```

---

For the mathematically inclined:

```
>>> n = 16581375
>>> (n//(256*256), n//256%256, n%256)
(253, 2, 255)
```

---

And for the logically inclined:

```
>>> n = 16581375
>>> (n >> 16, (n >> 8) & 0xFF, n & 0xFF)
(253, 2, 255)
```

Comment: What if `n` is 0? You'd better to use something like `format(n, '06x')` to make sure the 0 padding.

Comment: @falsetru Using the right `format()` fixed that :/... I was troubled by 16581375 not returning (255,255,255). But the actual max is 256*256*256-1 == 16777215, not the value given by the OP.